# Search for a value in a column and copy row to new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets, 'Data' and 'Source extract'. I want a code to search for keyword 'Dest' in 1st column from sheet'Data' and copy entire row and its next row to Source extract B column

Comment: Your question lacks any efforts of solving the problem yourself. Please take the  [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then edit your question and provide more detail before it gets locked.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code:

```
Sub DataToSourceExtract()
    Sheets("Data").Columns(1).Find("Dest").Resize(2).EntireRow.Copy _
        Sheets("Source Extract").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
End Sub
```